# Drupal form ahah element, problem with empty $_POST

Tags: php, drupal, ahah

I'm making a module for ubercart. It's nearly finished, but now I'm working on the admin page. I want the admin to be able to add options, like the poll module adds choices. The problem I have is that the admin form is generated through drupal_get_form, which leaves the `$_POST` empty. `$_POST['form_build_id']` seems to be needed to get the form from cache. Is there a way that the `$_POST['form_build_id']` can be accesses after a drupal_get_form? I read that it could be saved to the `$form_state` variable, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`drupal_get_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_get_form/6) saves the `$_POST` array into `$form['#post']`, I think.

if you want to look at how *poll* module adds choices, have a look at  [`poll_choice_js()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--poll--poll.module/function/poll_choice_js/6), which doesn't use `drupal_get_form()`, but does the building itself. It helped me understand the ahah process.

Comment: I ended up using the ahah helper module which was a little messy as well but brought me all the way in the end.