# how to get values in php from the submit form in drupal

Tags: php, forms, drupal, post

We have the form from where we need to access the values through a php code written.
But $_POST is not working in drupal.

We need to know how to access all the submit values  in php, please can anyone help us ?...

Comment: Check out this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819479/drupal-form-ahah-element-problem-with-empty-post. Quoting: "´drupal_get_form()´ saves the ´$_POST´ array into ´$form['#post']´"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this a form rendered in Drupal and also read from Drupal? Then it's easy with [the FAPI](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/group/form_api/7). You just need to add a submit callback to the form.

If it's your own module's form, just create another function with `_submit` suffix, like `mymodule_form_function_submit`. If it's someone else's form you will need to implement [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and have it add your submit callback like so:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'the_form') {
    $form['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_the_form_submit';
  }
}
```

Then simply implement the callback function.

```
function mymodule_the_form_submit($form, $form_state) {
  die('My name is ' . $form_state['values']['name']);
}
```

Using Drupal's built in Form API has the added benefit of separate validation from business logic. This means you can also add a validate callback, just like you addeed a submit one. If the validate callback calls [`form_set_error()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_error/7) then your submit callback won't even get called and so it can safely rely on having proper data.